# Get the y value of a UITextView's Keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, uitextview

[image]

I was wondering on how to get the y position of the input accessory view on the keyboard. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi Abdullah, your question [has already been asked and answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955888/ios-keyboard-location-and-orientation).  You can get the keyboard position by registering for the `UIKeyboard*` notifications.

Comment: I tried the solution but I don't get the input accessory view y position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup a `UITextViewDelegate` and implement the `textViewDidBeginEditing:` delegate method. When it is called, access the `inputAccessoryView` property of the text view. Then look at the view's `frame` property.

The frame is likely to be in window coordinates. You may need to covert the frame from window coordinates to another view's coordinates depending on your needs. See the `UIView convertRect:...` methods for details.

Comment: Thanks!!! I can't believe I did not think of that!

Answer (score 0):

Here is Apple's documentation on managing the keyboard: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Observe the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification notification and query the userInfo dictionary for the UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey to get an NSValue containing the CGRect of the keyboard.

More on UIKeyboardDidShowNotification here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIKeyboardDidShowNotification